# Django - how to specify a database for a model?

Tags: django, django-models, multiple-databases, django-database

Is there a way to specify that a model (or app, even) should only ever use one particular database?

I am working with a legacy database that I don't want to change. I have two databases - the 'default' is an sqlite one that could be used for admin etc, and the legacy one. I used inspectdb to create a model for (part of) the legacy database, and it has  `managed = False`. But is there a way to specify in the model itself that it only applies to a particular database?

I see that you can [specify `using=databasename`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database) in some query sets etc but this is no good for things like [Databrowse](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/databrowse/?from=olddocs) (and possibly also generic views?). It might be a short-coming of Databrowse that you can't specify a database, but it just seems like the right place to specify it is the model...

Then I thought maybe the answer is to write a custom [model manager](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) that only refers to my legacy database - but the docs don't mention anything like that.

Do I just have a different mental model of how multiple databases might be used, to the Django world?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as I know you can't specify the database directly with the model since it would kind of prevent the app from ever being reusable, but from what I can see in the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/

Answer (score 73):

You can't specify a database for a model, but you can define it in a custom DB router class.

```
# app/models.py
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ...

# app/dbrouters.py
from app.models import SomeModel
...
class MyDBRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """ reading SomeModel from otherdb """
        if model == SomeModel:
            return 'otherdb'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """ writing SomeModel to otherdb """
        if model == SomeModel:
            return 'otherdb'
        return None


# app/settings.py
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ('app.dbrouters.MyDBRouter',)
...
DATABASES = {
    ...
    'otherdb': {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

The simple solution is to set the manager to always use a specific database for the model. Look into Django's `using`.

Example:

```
class User(models.Model):
    birth_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'myotherapp_user'

User.objects = User.objects.using('myotherdb')
```

Then you can use `User.objects` and it will always use the `'myotherdb'` database instead of `'default'`.

Note that relations between models from different databases will not work, but this is an issue with Django since it does not support this out of the box.

Comment: how about not using `using`?

Comment: This looks like exactly what the most popular answer said wasn't possible.

Answer (score 12):

I found that you can route models pretty simply with this manager:

```
class SecondDbManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()

        # if `use_db` is set on model use that for choosing the DB
        if hasattr(self.model, 'use_db'):
            qs = qs.using(self.model.use_db)

        return qs
```

Just add `use_db='databasename'` and this manager to your model and it works.

Or to further simplify it I created a base model for it:

```
class SecondDbBase(models.Model):
    use_db = 'my_second_db'
    objects = SecondDbManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And with this all you need to do is extend it like so. Instead of:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
```

Just do this and it works:

```
class Customer(SecondDbBase):
```

PS. I'm not sure if it's a good practice or the best solution but it works and routing to other databases is a breeze :)

PPS. I've only ever used these for only reading and writing tables that are not managed by Django(`managed = False`) so if you need to create migrations for them, I'm not sure if it works or not. Might still need to use `DATABASE_ROUTERS` for that.

Comment: I added the first 2 classes to my `models.py` and changed my class definition as your example. But I got the error `TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`. For cross-compatibility between different versions of perl, replace `super()` for `super(SecondDbManager, self)`. Other than that, it worked perfectly, and I like that I can keep all changes in one place.

Comment: its working. thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Building on Mark's excellent answer - here's how to route both model read/write operations and migrations to different databases based on an attribute of the model

```
# app/models.py
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    class params:
        db = 'default'

class SomeOtherDbModel(models.Model):
    class params:
        db = 'otherdb'
    ...


# app/dbrouters.py
import app.models
allmodels = dict([(name.lower(), cls) for name, cls in app.models.__dict__.items() if isinstance(cls, type)])
...
class MyDBRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """ reading model based on params """
        return getattr(model.params, 'db')

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """ writing model based on params """
        return getattr(model.params, 'db')

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name = None, **hints):
        """ migrate to appropriate database per model """
        model = allmodels.get(model_name)
        return(model.params.db == db)


# app/settings.py
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ('app.dbrouters.MyDBRouter',)
...
DATABASES = {
    ...
    'otherdb': {
        ....
    }
}
```

See docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers

The model_name argument is passed at runtime as the lower case of the `model.__name__`, hence why we built the lookup dictionary by casting this attribute to lower.

Migrations should then be run as

```
python3 manage.py migrate app --database default
python3 manage.py migrate app --database otherdb
```

Answer (score 7):

Tested with Django 2.2 and pytest.
Just to streamline a bit the excellent @chris-schon [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60453322/10976040):

```py
class LegacyDbModel(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        _db = 'legacy_db_alias'


class LegacyDbRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """ reading model based on params """
        if not hasattr(model, 'Meta'):
            return None
        return getattr(model.Meta, '_db', None)

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """ writing model based on params """
        if not hasattr(model, 'Meta'):
            return None
        return getattr(model.Meta, '_db', None)
```

It has couple of minor benefits:

1. We don't need a `params` nested class for models from `default` DB.
2. We leverage `Meta` nested class which is already part of Django.
3. Router works without `allow_migrate` even for tests.

The only drawback is that we need to inherit from `Meta` explicitly:

```py
class LegacyModel(LegacyDbModel):
    # ... docs, fields, etc.

    class Meta(LegacyDbModel.Meta):
        managed = False
        db_table = 'legacy_table'
```

But even that is more [aligned with how Django works](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance).
[Remember](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id2):

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 0):

You can set *objects* to default for your database or create specific *objects*.

**models.py**:

```
class YourManagerName(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().using('YourDatabaseName')

class YourModel(models.Model):
    # table fields
    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager
    your_objects = YourManagerName() # The your specific manager
```

**views.py**:

```
def get_data(request):
    default_db_data = YourModel.objects.all()
    specific_db_data = YourModel.your_objects.all()
```