# Pulling Data From Other Data Bases In Django

Tags: django, database

I'm new to Django . I am totally confused now . I am going to create a new feature to our product. In this users can connect their data bases and pull data from their data bases .

The main challange is that, user can connect data bases like Oracle , Sql Server, Mysql etc....

I have done lots of research , but I am not able to found any package for this .

So now , I am confused that , is it possible to connect an external data base and copy the data from that data bases to our project.

I have seen one package called "Appache airflow" (https://airflow.apache.org/)

But I am not sure this will support for Django . If some one having any idea please help to solve this issue .

Comment: Checkout [Apache Gobblin](https://gobblin.apache.org/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider database routing?

It few words,  you can define in Django multiple databases (they can be different so mysql, postgres, ecc...) and based on the action required let Django fetch the data from a  specific database.

Here is the doc  related to the django database routing -> [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing)

Plus at this link, you can find a comment on django database routing and how to define it: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66282220/7597536)