# Django DRF Post for Multiple Database Connections

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Fairly new to DRF and I am working on a project that connects to multiple databases. I am able to use get to retrieve data from whichever specified database however when using post I get an error related to my database connection and table name. I think I need to reference the database in the post method but I am striking out researching the issue. Anyone know how to reference the specific database for self.create ?

```
class AdminView(
    mixins.ListModelMixin, 
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    generics.GenericAPIView):
        serializer_class = AdminMeterLakeSerializer
        queryset = AdminMeterLake.objects.using('testdb').all()

        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.create(request.data, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This is because your serializer's `create` uses the default manager of your `AdminMeterLake` model, which in turn uses the default db. One approach to solve this is to override your serializer's `create` method to use the specific db you want, or change the default manager of `AdminMeterLake` to use your specific db

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to create context manager. That will allow to effectively control DB connections in future:

- Add DB router to `config/settings.py`

```
...
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    'config.routers.DynamicDatabaseRouter',
]
...
```

- Create `DynamicDatabaseRouter` in `config/routers.py`:

```
from contextvars import ContextVar
active_db = ContextVar("DB to use", default=None)

def get_active_db():
    # return default connection if not set
    db = active_db.get(None)
    return db if db else 'default'

def set_active_db(connection_name):
    return active_db.set(connection_name)

class DynamicDatabaseRouter:

    @staticmethod
    def _get_db(*args, **kwargs):
        db = get_active_db()
        return db

    db_for_read = _get_db
    db_for_write = _get_db
```

- Add context manager into `config/context.py`:

```
from contextlib import ContextDecorator
from config.routers import set_active_db


class db(ContextDecorator):

    def __init__(self, connection_name):
        self.connection_name = connection_name

    def __enter__(self):
        set_active_db(connection_name)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        set_active_db(None)
        return False
```

And your class should be updated to:

```
from config.context import db

class AdminView(
    mixins.ListModelMixin, 
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    generics.GenericAPIView):
        serializer_class = AdminMeterLakeSerializer
        queryset = AdminMeterLake.objects.using('testdb').all()

        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            with db('testdb'):
                return self.create(request.data, *args, **kwargs)
```

The flow is:

1. When you run `with db('testdb')` the `__enter__` method is called
2. `active_db` context variable value will be updated to `testdb`
3. database router read `active_db` value and use `testdb` connection
4. When operation is complete `__exit__` will be called and context variable value will be reverted to `None` *

- if `active_db` value is `None` router will return `default` connection

## OR 1

You may simply use [django-dynamic-db-router](https://django-dynamic-db-router.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

*Also this [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676143/using-multiple-databases-with-django) may be useful*

## OR 2

You may set custom [`Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/) class for database `Model`:

```
from django.db import models

class AdminMeterLake(models.Model):
    ...
    col_name_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    col_name_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

    objects = models.Manager().using('testdb')
```

In this case `testdb` will be used by default and you will be able to set `queryset = AdminMeterLake.objects.all()` instead of `queryset = AdminMeterLake.objects.using('testdb').all()`

- `models.Manager().using('testdb')` way is didn't tested by me and it is just theoretical solution (but it should work I guess...)

Comment: This is amazing! This is hands down the most helpful response I have ever gotten. I instituted your initial solution utilizing the config/context and config/routers. I was getting an odd error 'AttributeError: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'data'. I was not sure what this was but I noticed the line it flagged was with the "serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)". Was not really sure what this was but thought I should probably overwrite the default serializer. I switched up the post method and now it works great!

Comment: @RobbieEisenrich Glad to hear that my answer was helpful. Don't forget to vote up for answers that helped you.

Comment: @rzlvmp, thanks for detailed answer. What if I don't provide context manager - will DB router work as - reading from 'slave' DB and writing into 'default' DB?

Comment: @OmPrakash if you will change default DB connections for db_for_read (return 'slave' if connection not set) and db_for_write (return 'default' if connection not set) it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Working off of the absolute boss rzlvmp's solution one, I was able to get a working solution capable of routing databases on demand.

Project settings:

```
'''
    DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    'config.routers.DynamicDatabaseRouter',
    ]
'''
```

config/routers.py which I placed into my root directory with manage.py

```
   from contextvars import ContextVar
   active_db = ContextVar("DB to use", default=None)

    def get_active_db():
        # return default connection if not set
        db = active_db.get(None)
        return db if db else 'default'

    def set_active_db(connection_name):
        return active_db.set(connection_name)

    class DynamicDatabaseRouter:

        @staticmethod
        def _get_db(*args, **kwargs):
            db = get_active_db()
            return db

        db_for_read = _get_db
        db_for_write = _get_db
```

config/context.py

```
from contextlib import ContextDecorator
from config.routers import set_active_db


class db(ContextDecorator):

    def __init__(self, connection_name):
        self.connection_name = connection_name

    def __enter__(self):
        
        set_active_db(self.connection_name)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        set_active_db(None)
        return False
```

for my serilizers.py

```
from .models import AdminMeterLake
from rest_framework import request, serializers

class AdminMeterLakeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AdminMeterLake
        fields = ['testa', 'testb', 'testc']
```

for my views.py, please note I did not include all my imports

```
from config.context import db

class AdminView(
    mixins.ListModelMixin, 
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = AdminMeterLakeSerializer
    queryset = AdminMeterLake.objects.using('testdb').all()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        with db('testdb'):
            serializer = AdminMeterLakeSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.errors)
```