# Select From Another DataBase in Django Rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, datamodel

In Rest FrameWork Django I want use from another DataBase in my View
Now I can use data of databse model of django created .
I want select a database of another program and show in api

Please Help Me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use multiple databases in your Django app.

You can look at Django's original documentation [Multiple databases | Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/).

Also, I did some research on the internet for your question, and I found some posts.

- [How to set up multiple databases on django](https://dev.to/minhvuong1/how-to-set-up-multiple-databases-on-django-1c76)
- [Using Multiple Databases with Django | Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676143/using-multiple-databases-with-django)

Otherwise, If you want to use other application databases, you need to create an API gateway for the other application.

Maybe you can solve this issue connect with your other app database manually without an API gateway:

- [PostgreSQL - Python Interface | tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_python.htm)
- [SQLite - Python | tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm)
- [MySQL - Python | W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp)

I hope it helps!