# Django ModelForm save to another database

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a set up with **multiple databases**: let's call them `db1`, `db2` and `db3`. `db1` is default.

I now have a ModelForm that is meant to save an object `Customer` to `db2`.

```
class CustomerCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ["name", "type"]
```

My view:

```
if "create" in request.POST:
    f = CustomerCreateForm(data=request.POST)
    customer = f.save(commit=False)  # Error -> no table 'customer' on database 'db1'
    customer.date_joined = datetime.now()
    customer.save(using='db2')
```

It appears that the `save()` method does not have a `using` argument. How can I save an instance of `Customer` to `db2` using a `ModelForm`? Of course I can always use a simple `Form` instead but I wanted to see if there is a correct way of doing this via `ModelForm`?

EDIT: This issue also appears when checking if the form is valid.

```
f = CustomerCreateForm(data=request.POST)
if f.is_valid(): # Error: No model Customer on database db1
    # some more code...
```

Comment: is this what you're looking for?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519143/django-how-to-specify-a-database-for-a-model

Comment: no, my database routers are set up correctly. calling `modelinstance.save(using=db2)` works fine for me. however, you cannot use the `using` argument when saving a model instance from a `ModelForm`. i.e. `f.save(commit=False, using='db2')` - unexpected argument `using`

Comment: Did manage to save instance to specific db? Could you share your code?